# Searching HTML text files with lines that get truncated

Tags: python, file

I am using the following code to search though an HTML files searching for a specific string.  The string appears multiple times when searching through the files, however, when parsing the line in Python it appears as one *very* long line and the string is not found.

```
substring = 'FundProfile/FundProfileView/GHF'

with open('test.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if substring in line:
            print(line[substring.rfind('Fund')-10:substring.rfind('Fund')+30])
```

This is line 1736 of the file where the bulk of the data exists in one very very very long line which is getting truncated in Python and hence the search string can not be found.
`<span class="s-ico" style="display:none"><span sort="asc" class="ui-grid-ico-sort ui-icon-asc ui-state-disabled ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-n ui-sort-ltr"></span><span sort="desc" class="ui-grid-ico-sort ui-icon-desc ui-state-disabled ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s ui-sort-ltr"></span></span></div></th><th id="table_search_results_FavoriteFundID" role="columnheader" class="ui-state-default ui-th-column ui-th-ltr" title="Select" style="width: 15px;"><span class="checkboxsearch"><input type="checkbox" name="chkfundsall" id="chkfundsall"><label for="chkfundsall"></label></span> </th><th id="table_search_results_FundName" role="columnheader" class="ui-state-default ui-th-column ui-th-ltr" title="Fund N ...'`

I have tried to split the line string into an array but it appears that the line is being truncated.  How can I deal with very large lines when parsing through text files in Python?

Comment: Just how big is this line? In windows, In order to recreate your example, I created a file with 244MB characters in one line, plus a few other lines with a few characters and python read all that and even matched substrings inside it.

Comment: File itself is 5MB, 3000 lines.  In the text is HTML and a lot of Javascript.  From Notepad++ the search term is there over 3000 times on one specific line.

Answer (score 0):

The long length of the line is a not causing it to be truncated — the problem is with your code.

The text of line 1736 shown in your answer doesn't contain the substring `'FundProfile/FundProfileView/GHF'`. Even if it did, the `substring.rfind('Fund')` you have is finding the index of `'Fund'` in **`substring`**, **not** in `line`, so using it as though it was relative to `line`'s contents as you're doing isn't correct.

Something like this would be a valid way of doing things:

```
testfile = 'FundProfile_FundProfileView_GHF.txt'

substring = 'FundProfile/FundProfileView/GHF'

with open(testfile, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if substring in line:
            print(line[line.rfind('Fund')-10: line.rfind('Fund')+30])
```

Comment: It's in the text file many times but it is being truncated. Here is one example:  <a href="/FundProfile/FundProfileView/GHF/63267" target="_blank">TimesSquare Global Health Care Fund</a>

Comment: When I add that to the end of my (relatively short) test file, it finds it with the code in my answer. My main point is that the code in your question is wrong and will never work for the reasons explained. Also note that `rfind()` searches backwards, sousing it will find the last occurrence of string passed it in in each line of file, even if there's only one.